# Charge cycles increase?

Tags: macos, mac, battery, charging

This is a bit weird, I've been doing everything to keep the battery health great and that's what i achieved so far. it's going through 99-100%, but the thing is.. those charging cycles thing are increasing everyday, yesterday it was 32 and today it became 36 even though the health is going well, How to keep it low ? isn't the health dedicated to those cycles ? and which is more important the health or the cycles ?

Answer (score 1):

Your charge cycles increase every time you cycle through the the equivalent of a full battery charge. Mac laptops made since the "unibody" style was released use lithium polymer batteries which should retain 80% of their battery power after 1000 charges. (So if you got 7 hours out of the box, you should still be getting 5.5 hours.)

In general I wouldn't worry too much about your battery health. Lithium polymer is extremely flexible as a battery technology and Apple makes some of the best batteries in the electronics industry. The only way to really ruin the battery is to keep it plugged in 100% of the time. Unplug it at least once a month for 5-10 hours and you should be fine. With 1000 recharge cycles guaranteed Apple is expecting you to replace the system before you ever suffer issues with battery life.

Comment: Apple also updated their battery page, which is quite well written: http://www.apple.com/batteries/

Comment: so there's no way to keep it down ? thats stupid, lets say i recharge it twice a day to 100%, thats about 4 cycles a day, thats about less than a year for the battery to completely go down ?

Comment: No a cycle is only reached when you go from 0% to 100%. If you plug your laptop in to fully charge when it's at 75%, it will only count as a 1/4 charge cycle, since it was only charged the final 25% of its capacity. Make sense? The only way you can use 4 cycles a day is to fully deplete and fully charge the battery 4 times, which is next to impossible with how great the batteries are.